# Request for experience: when has having only 16GB on your iPhone inconvenienced you?

Tags: iphone, memory

Today I regretted having only 2 GB on my Shuffle, because it meant I could not store the three most recent episodes of my favorite podcasts; but so far I have never used the full 16 GB on my 2nd Generation iPod Touch.

Now I am looking at replacing the iPod Touch and a very early Android cellphone with an iPhone 4S.  The contract will be $1680 over two years, so the $200 cost difference between the 16GB and 64GB model verges on negligible; but I care; I could get the small size and donate $200 to pancreatic cancer research.

What are people doing with the second 16 or 48GB of storage on their iPhones?  Movies?  Whole music collections?  DOS emulators?

Presumably people who have 16GB iPhones made that capacity choice based on what they thought their needs would be.  For those who subsequently discovered that 16GB was not always enough, what were the circumstances?

First-hand answers are more useful than second-hand, though if you have a friend, colleague, or family member who frequently berates him or herself for being stingy with memory, the details would be useful too.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question with a right answer.

Comment: Some people load iTunes movies and TV shows on their devices. Others have 100+ GB music libraries. Still others have 100's of games (some can require up to a GB of space each). And still others take tons of pictures and videos with their devices. People vary greatly and so do their habits. Buy a device that fits your lifestyle.

Comment: "iMovie on a long trip" is a right answer.

Comment: @Daniel, the original wording of the question was "When have you regretted having only 16GB," what definitely has right answers.  The rephrasing is a bit anodyne for my taste and may encourage banality.

Comment: @cksum, I think people who have a year's experience with a tool are more aware of the tool's capabilities than I can possibly imagine.  Have you ever regretted having only 16 GB on your iPhone?  What was the circumstance?

Comment: No. Never. But I am a minimalist. Daniel makes a good point as this is pretty subjective. A 750 GB HD may be good for you, but I may need a 1 GB. I'm sure you know your habits best. On the other hand, I can see if you've never owned an iPhone before. You may be unfamiliar with the App Store and what's available there. I guess it comes down to how strictly you want to adhere to the faq. Because at the end of the day, Daniel is correct, there is no "right" answer. I may be fine with a 16 GB iPhone, you on the other hand could never live with it. However, none of us are wrong (or right).

Comment: @cksum, I know what habits I have given the tools I am using now, but that is a poor substitute for the real-world experience of people using different tools.  The question is emphatically not whether 16 GB is enough for you or anyone.  The question, before it was changed, was for field reports from current owners of a 16GB iPhone who had ever felt regret that they had only 16GB.  I am confidant that I know with 98% likelihood the answer to "does a minimalist require more than 16GB?" so I would not ask.

Comment: I think Thomas put good work into the question to explain what and why he was looking to accomplish with the question. Rather than just ask an unrefined "which should I get" he framed the issue in terms of functionality that real people used extra ram to accomplish. Of course some would never spring $200 to save an hour or two in manually managing storage - others can't pay enough to have the iOS version of an automatic transmission - room to spare to set it and forget it in iTunes.

Comment: The only reason I get 32 GB or 64 GB devices is if I plan on putting A LOT, let me be more clear, A LOT of video on it. If you're just putting audio and apps on your device, then 16 GB and definitely 32 GB will be sufficient. Good for you, I like that you're donating money to a good cause! +1

Comment: @JackHumphries, I wonder if there are people who bought a 32GB device, and then found out that it was not enough.  There does not seem to be any good way to ask that here :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Video Capture, more photos, larger image sensor and better camera on the iPhone 4S means I'll spring for 32. Even with iCloud and all the music streaming options, I find I always want 4 GB of core music (and another 2.5 of podcasts) with me. Having room for more serious app and book (PDF) storage will be very nice.

The 14 GB iPhone 4 I've used since it launched was sufficient except for maybe a handful of times where I wanted more space. Especially when using iMovie to assemble slide shows and short video updates on a longer trip. Also, if an apple keynote or other hour long video comes out, I don't have the space to accommodate such videos.

[image]
[image]
Those are the few times when "the 16" wasn't enough for me. I now don't take several databases with me using bento and filemaker pro since I want more space for songs and camera footage.

---

I initially thought of a white 32 iPod Touch and the smallest black 4S - but having all the space and speed in one package makes it more of a computer to me. I can grab a bluetooth keyboard and get short work done if needed. I'm also quite eager for AirPlay and a 4S.

Comment: That's exactly the kind of answer I was seeking.  The 2nd Generation iPod Touch has no camera; the only content I have added to it directly is the occasional app download and WFMU radio archive.  Thanks for the use case.